# Testing an async celery task with pytest results in "no attribute 'delay'"

Tags: pytest, celery, django-celery

I'm implementing [celery-batches](https://pypi.org/project/celery-batches/) to eliviate a problem with thousands of small tasks being loaded into the queue. This app will batch together these small jobs so that they can be processed more efficiently.

The problem I'm having in testing this functionality is that if you have celery in eager mode, like you would in a test suite, `celery-batches` doesn't batch up the tasks and just sends the `*args, **kwargs` through as if it was directly calling the task.

The project is using:

- `celery==5.3.1`
- `pytest==7.3.2`
- `pytest-django==4.5.2`

So I've tried various ways to make use of a celery worker in a single test. Currently running as the docs suggest to have a worker embedded in another thread for the duration of a test ([docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.3.1/userguide/testing.html#celery-worker-embed-live-worker))

```
# conftest.py


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    return {
        "broker_url": "redis://redis:6379/2",  # running a docker compose dev setup with redis available
        "result_backend": "redis://redis:6379/2",
    }


@pytest.fixture
def celery_worker_parameters():
    return {
        "perform_ping_check": False,
        "broker_connection_retry_on_startup": True,
    }


@pytest.fixture
def not_eager(settings):
    settings.CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
```

```
# test_my_task.py

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_task_call(
    django_capture_on_commit_callbacks,
    my_obj_factory,
    mocker,
    celery_worker,
    not_eager,
):
    mock_notification_task = mocker.patch(
        "project.tasks.notify.delay"
    )
    objs = [my_obj_factory() for _x in range(500)]
    with django_capture_on_commit_callbacks(execute=True) as callbacks:
        for o in objs:
            my_signal(sender=None, objs=[o])

    # Verify we triggered all the signal calls to the notification call
    assert len(callbacks) == len(objs)
```

So this test calls a function that's attached to a django signal that in turn calls a celery task which you see being patched.

Running this I get a warning from Kombu, `No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'` and the error I'm seeing;

```
[ERROR][2023-09-28 21:44:06,337][signal] Signal handler <bound method DjangoWorkerFixup.on_worker_process_init of <celery.fixups.django.DjangoWorkerFixup object at 0xffff7eaaee50>> raised: OperationalError(2006, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 276, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 164, in on_worker_process_init
    self._maybe_close_db_fd(c.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 172, in _maybe_close_db_fd
    _maybe_close_fd(fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 38, in _maybe_close_fd
    os.close(fh.fileno())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2006, '')
[WARNING][2023-09-28 21:44:06,343][warnings] /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:498: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

FAILED tests/test_commands/test_notification.py::test_notify - django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
ERROR tests/test_commands/test_clever_tap_notification.py::test_clever_tap_picks_changed - AttributeError: 'notify_clever_tap' object has no attribute 'delay'
```

This is a celery task, so I don't understand the `AttributeError`;

```
@shared_task(
    autoretry_for=(
        requests.exceptions.RequestException,
        db.OperationalError,
        db.utils.OperationalError,
    ),
    retry_backoff=2,
    max_retries=8,
    ignore_result=True,
)
def notify(obj_ids):
    
    pass


@shared_task(
    base=Batches,
    flush_every=12,
    flush_interval=10,
)
def batch_notify(batched_requests: list[SimpleRequest]):
    _ids = []

    for batch in batched_requests:
        obj_list = batch.kwargs.get("obj_ids")
        _ids.extend(obj_list)

    chunks = list(chunked(_ids, 100))
    for obj_ids in chunks:
        notify.delay(obj_ids)
```